# Check which list is the largerst

Tags: android

I have a question. How can I check which list is the largest and have the most elements. I have 10 lists, but some of them could be null. How can I check which list is the largest and protect from null?
This is what I have:

```
if(listOfPressureDataToPlot!=null &&listOfPressureDataToPlot.size()>=listOfDBPDataToPlot.size()&& listOfPressureDataToPlot.size()>=listOfSBPDataToPlot.size()&& listOfPressureDataToPlot.size()>=listOfTempDataToPlot.size()&&
                        listOfPressureDataToPlot.size()>=listOfBIODataToPlot.size()&& listOfPressureDataToPlot.size()>=listOfCENDataToPlot.size()&& listOfPressureDataToPlot.size()>=listOfGLUDataToPlot.size()&&
                        listOfPressureDataToPlot.size()>=listOfHBDDataToPlot.size()&& listOfPressureDataToPlot.size()>=listOfOBBDataToPlot.size()&& listOfPressureDataToPlot.size()>=listOfOBGDataToPlot.size()&&
                        listOfPressureDataToPlot.size()>=listOfOBKDataToPlot.size()&& listOfPressureDataToPlot.size()>=listOfRANDataToPlot.size()&& listOfPressureDataToPlot.size()>=listOfTALDataToPlot.size()&&
                        listOfPressureDataToPlot.size()>=listOfWAGDataToPlot.size()&& listOfPressureDataToPlot.size()>=listOfWZRDataToPlot.size()){
                    dateValue = checkDateToPopUp(listOfPressureDataToPlot, listOfPressureToPlot, x1).getFirst();
                    setMexTable(listOfPressureDataToPlot);
                }
```

but this solution doesn't protect me if one of this list is null. How can I implement simple code to check which list has most elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put all the lists into another `ArrayList`and iterate through them like so:

```
   ArrayList maxList = null;

   ArrayList aLists = new ArrayList();
   aLists.add(listOfOBKDataToPlot);
   aLists.add(listOfRANDataToPlot);
   aLists.add(listOfTALDataToPlot);
   aLists.add(listOfWZRDataToPlot);

   for (Object object : aLists)
   {
        ArrayList aList = (ArrayList) object;
        if (aList != null && aList.size() > maxList.size())
        {
            maxList = aList;
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Dear Its same like finding out maximum value from 10 numbers. Here is the [logic of finding out maximum from Array](http://www.phanderson.com/C/arraymax.html).

I know you don't have array but you can create it with size of different ArrayList you have, you can also check NULL value while adding.

Answer (score 0):

You could make an Array with 10 Element of Type int, then you could initialize every entry with 0. Each entry stands for the size of a List, so you could check if the lis != null and then put list.size in the corresponding entry. For example something like:

```
int sizes[] = new int[10];
if (list[i] != null) sizes[i] = list[i].size()
```

Then you could easily check for the maximum in sizes.
list[i] means the listOfBIO, listOfHBD, etc.
Yould could copy the if clause for every list (just put in the real name),
or put all lists in an Array, so you could iterate about them.